# Explicit Finite Difference Scheme For Approxating a p.d.e

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, finite-differences

$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{x^2+1}\frac{du}{dx}]$

I am trying to approximate this pde with a finite difference scheme but I am confused with the d/dx. Do I just take the derivative of 1/(x^2+1) and d/dx * du/dx = d^2/dx. Or is it a product rule?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, either do the product rule and then discretize, or discretize the equation as is. I'll derive them both:

---

**Product Rule**
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{x^2+1} \frac{du}{dx}\right] $$
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{x^2+1} \right]\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{1}{x^2+1}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} $$
$$\frac{du}{dt} = -\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{1}{x^2+1}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} $$

Then you discretize that. For example using central differences for space and forward for time:

$$u_i^{n+1} = u_i^n + \Delta t\left(-\frac{2x_i}{(x_i^2+1)^2}\frac{u_{i+1}^n-u_{i-1}^n}{2\Delta x} + \frac{1}{x_i^2+1}\frac{u_{i+1}^n - 2u_i^n + u_{i-1}^n}{\Delta x^2} 
\right) $$

Then you simply solve that computing $u^{n+1}_i$from the data in the previous time step, starting with the initial condition of your problem.

---

**As is**

Alternatively, you could discretize the equation as is. There you treat all of 
$$\frac{1}{x^2+1} \frac{du}{dx} $$ as if it was a single function.
For example:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{x^2+1} \frac{du}{dx}\right] \approx \frac{1}{2\Delta x}\left(\left.\frac{1}{x_{i+1}^2+1} \frac{du}{dx}\right|_{i+1} - \left.\frac{1}{x_{i-1}^2+1} \frac{du}{dx}\right|_{i-1}\right) $$

Then you discretize each of the derivatives again, but using $i+1$ and $i-1$ as the center points.
$$ \frac{1}{2\Delta x}\left(\left.\frac{1}{x_{i+1}^2+1} \frac{du}{dx}\right|_{i+1} - \left.\frac{1}{x_{i-1}^2+1} \frac{du}{dx}\right|_{i-1}\right) \approx \frac{1}{2\Delta x}\left(\frac{1}{x_{i+1}^2+1}\left( \frac{u_{i+2}-u_i}{2 \Delta x}\right) - \frac{1}{x_{i-1}^2+1} \left( \frac{u_i - u_{i-2}}{2 \Delta x}\right)\frac{du}{dx}\right)$$

Then taking into account the time derivative, the final equation is:
$$ u_i^{n+1} =u_i^n + \Delta t\left(\frac{1}{x_{i+1}^2+1}\left( \frac{u_{i+2}^n-u_i^n}{4 \Delta x^2}\right) - \frac{1}{x_{i-1}^2+1} \left( \frac{u_i^n - u_{i-2}^n}{4 \Delta x^2}\right)\right)$$

Both approaches are correct. Not that in the second you end up calling points that 2 steps away from the point of interest. This makes the boundary conditions a bit harder to take into account, so the first method is usually preferred.